# Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021)

Tags: packages, installing, mactex, tlmgr, tinytex

I installed MacTex 2021, and in /usr/local/texlive, there is only 2021 file. But when I tried to install a package in terminal, it still says
" Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021).
Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details."
I am wondering how I can fix this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: maxtex? (did you mean mactex?) unless you explicitily removed texlive 2020 installing texlive 2021 will mean that you have both installed, and which is used will depend on yoru PATH. It appears that you are using a texllive 2020 `tlmgr`

Comment: yes, that was a typo. I have un installed texlive 2020. but echo $PATH gives me "/Users/aw/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/aw/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin"

Comment: I don't have a mac so probably a mactex user should answer but what does `which -a tlmgr` report and what does `tlmgr --version` report ?

Comment: tlmgr --version reports "tlmgr revision 57705 (2021-02-10 23:57:28 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /Users/aw/Library/TinyTeX
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2020"

Comment: which -a tlmgr reports "/usr/local/bin/tlmgr
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr"

Comment: How did you install TeX Live 2021? What OS version are you using?

Comment: so you have two versions of tlmgr installed, and are using the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have TinyTeX installed.

So there are two options. Either you want to switch to MacTeX (which is a full TeXlive distribution) or you want to upgrade your TinyTeX. The latter is documented on the TinyTeX homepage:

> If you see an error message “Remote repository newer than local”, it means it is time for you to upgrade (reinstall) TinyTeX manually:
>
> `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`

If you did install a full MacTeX distribution, you should uninstall TinyTeX (which should be just `rm -r ~/Library/TinyTeX` although I don't see it in your path in your comment).

Comment: Thank you. I found uninstall button in R studio.