# TeXLive 2022 installation using CTAN texlive2022-20220321.iso; tlmgr says it is 2021 version and refuses to cooperate!

Tags: texlive, installing, tlmgr, update

**EDITED:**

A previous question to this forum by user 'mab' [(texlive & tlmgr: cannot load tlmgr etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624378/tlmgr-cannot-load-tex-live-database-from)---and particularly the answers -- do not provide any information **re:** how the O/S and the TeXLive distribution are at odd with each other.

Particularly, the reply *"that is the debian system tlmgr not the one you showed,"* is not helpful to me. TeXLive has a tlmgr. I would ***not*** think that Debian (part of the O/S) has any component called "tlmgr"---which is what the answer seems to imply. If that answer is intended to mean something else...well....then that should be made very clear.
My O/S is  **Linux Mint Cinnamon v21.1** which is some sort of witches' brew of Ubuntu and Debian. The "debian tlmgr", as referred to by user David Carlisle, is in my case the same one installed with (and I assume, **by**!) the TeXLive 2022 ISO-DVD which I used.

And, while we are at it: for absolute clarity: would someone confirm for me that the ISO-DVD version ***is*** the so-called "vanilla" version? After my nuke-and-pave on ~19 February, I **did not** choose to install any "package" version offered by the so-called 'synaptic package manager' of Mint. But when I did a CLEAN install of Mint this packaged version was somehow included. That comes as a surprise to me.

So, I was expecting no conflicts by nuking and paving and doing a clean install of both the OS and then, immediately afterwards, TexLive 2022.

TUG / CTAN has this documents related to **tlmgr** and **Debian/Ubuntu,** [TexLive and Debian / Ubuntu](https://tug.org/texlive/debian.html). There, it indicates how to install from an internet connection to CTAN or another mirror, but there's nothing (that I can see) about massaging and managing an installation created by the TexLive ISO-DVD method so that I would be able to employ **tlmgr**

I apologize to all if this sounds grumpy, but I have just spent four (4) full working days repairing my prior installation (corrupted while trying to get tlmgr to work), only to be told that I was essentially SOL, and that a nuke-and-pave would be required. Having done all that and a clean install from DVD it seems that I am pretty much back at my original point-of-departure (i.e., **NO tlmgr** functionality!). It is beginning to look pretty bleak from my end...

****END OF EDIT****

**&&&new edit&&&**
Response to **Enkorvaks** who suggested [similar question about tlmgr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673389/older-than-remote-repository-but-2022-had-been-installed-and-now-need-to-update),
I ran locate tlmgr as suggested there. Here is what I got as a reply:

```
/home/username/.local/share/RecentDocuments/tlmgr.html.desktop
/home/username/.local/share/okular/docdata/1444.README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md.xml
/home/username/texmf/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
/home/username/texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
/usr/bin/tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/tlmgr.1
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/tlmgr.man1.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgrbasics
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/LICENSE
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/README.md
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/fig
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/latexmkrc
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/actions.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/examples.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/mirrors.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/options.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/preface.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/schemes_and_collections.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/body/syntex.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/fig/collection.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn/fig/scheme.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgrbasics/README
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgrbasics/tlmgr.pdf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/support/tlmgrbasics/tlmgr.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/tlmgr.html
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-common/tlmgr-gui.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-de/tlmgr-general-options.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-de/tlmgr-gui.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-de/tlmgr-paper-options.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc/texlive/texlive-sr/images/tl2019-tlmgr-tl-old-gui-sr.png
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
/usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tlpobj/tlmgr-intro-zh-cn.tlpobj
/usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tlpobj/tlmgrbasics.tlpobj
/usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tltcl/tlmgr.gif
/usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive/tlmgr.html
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive/texlive-common/tlmgr-gui.png
/usr/share/man/man1/tlmgr.1.gz
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
/var/lib/texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

all of which looks like the tip of the Titanic's iceberg. So YES, this does confirm that the **** Mint installer went ahead and installed the OLDER package of TexLive and now I have to deal with the conflicts.

*****end of this edit*****

Latest TeXLive distro was downloaded (=TexLive 2022) from the TUG.ORG link, [*see the CTAN page, here*](https://ctan.mirror.globo.tech/systems/texlive/Images/) on February 19 2023

Specifically the ISO file downloaded from CTAN was  **texlive2022-20220321.iso** and
**texlive2022-20220321.iso.sha512** (text file of the SHA512 hash); the SHA512 was calculated and the ISO image was verified.

I burned the ISO to a DVD (i.e., created DVD that should be equivalent to TUG-members' annual distribution).

I allowed the DVD installer to install TeXLive; it created the directory /usr/local/texlive/2022. No user intervention here!

I updated the $PATH; the PATH was verified using 'echo $PATH' & shown to be valid during this terminal session:

```
<username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022
```

I then ran 'texhash' to be sure that all files were discovered and aligned along the appropriate celestial axes:

```
<username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022$ sudo texhash       
    texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R...  **<<<< note that this file was    created Feb 20,2023, so it is part of the new installation of "TeXLive 2022"**
    texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
    texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
    texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
    texhash: Done.
<username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022$
```

NOTE--all the commands below issued from **the /usr/local/texlive/2022 path**

I then initiated the user tree:

```
<username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022$ sudo tlmgr init-usertree
```

I then tried to **install** a package that is *not yet* on the 2022 distro, *but it exists on CTAN* (**and** I've been told it will make it into the 2023 distro):

```
<username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022$ sudo tlmgr install pagelayout
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
**tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022).**
Cross release updates are only supported with
update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
<username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022$ sudo tlmgr --version
**tlmgr revision 60693 (2021-10-04 04:24:25 +0200)**
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive  **<<< created Feb 19, 2023**
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2021
username>@<username>-<computername>:/usr/local/texlive/2022
```

this is reminiscent of the problem experienced by another[*see: Local Tex Live...*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598423/local-tex-live-2020-is-older-than-remote-repository-2021), but this is a Linux installation, not Mac and **there is no TinyTex**

So....now what?!

Comment: It seems that you are calling `tlmgr` from the Debian TeX distribution. Using `which tlmgr` should show the difference. Maybe using the absolute path of the `tlmgr` can work.

Comment: Have a look at this, as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673389/ (also Debian Linux based issue) as your problem is likely to be similar, with a similar solution .

Comment: I suspect you only set your PATH not the PATH used by sudo

Comment: sudo sees a different path as David says, but you also need to prepend the TL 2022 install in the path, otherwise the older TL 2021 binaries in `/usr/bin/` will be seen first and used.  Executing commands from a specific folder doesn't change the PATH.