# sudo tlmgr --gui does not recognize my SU / admin privilege, flags "command not found". tlmgr --gui works, but no functionality!

Tags: tlmgr, texlive2022

tlmgr was the cause of many problems (see my previous posts), which disappeared after a nuke-and-pave. I then was able to access tlmgr with standard gui interface.
Now (a week later) I can run tlmgr from terminal, but response is:

```
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
```

If I try to run as `sudo tlmgr --gui`, it returns `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`

How do I get HAL to open the bay doors?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675989/texlive-2022-installation-using-ctan-texlive2022-20220321-iso-tlmgr-says-it-is#comment1679315_675989

Comment: this is identical to your previous question and has the same answer

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, `tlmgr` is on your path, which is why you can run it (without being able to do anything). It does not, however, appear to be on `root`'s path, so running `sudo tlmgr` comes up with `command not found`.

To solve this, you can either use the full path `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr` (substitute your path there), or you can add the path to `root`'s path variable. For the second, start a shell as `root` (the easiest way to do that is `sudo -i`), and use an editor you are happy to use to edit `~/.bashrc` (assuming `bash` is your shell of choice, also note that this is `root`'s `.bashrc`, not yours), and add a command similar to `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}`. Once you save that file, and return to your normal shell, `sudo tlmgr` should work as you expect. (I think I've got the paths right, but am going from memory here, since I don't have a local install of TeX Live 2022 at my fingertips right now)

As an aside, usually I don't install TeX Live as root, I create a dedicated `texlive` user (with home directory `/usr/local/texlive`), and install under that. To use that, run `sudo su - texlive` to start a shell as the `texlive` user, then just use `tlmgr` to do admin as needed. So far, I have had no trouble at all with this set-up, but I am the only one using that computer. Of course, you will need to set your `PATH` appropriately if you do that.

Edit: Thank you to @DavidCarlisle (on another question) for the reminder that putting the texlive path first makes certain problems go away.

Comment: Users enkorvaks, david carlisle, and terdon: thanks, got it now! Not sufficient to have correct $PATH , must also be correct 'sudoers' path [https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands] is the critical item in this case !!!! All solved now, thanks for your patience (I am simultaneously on the steep part of the learning curve for BOTH Linux AND TexLive!